# how to post simple ID (jquery ajax) to Action method in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an category drop down list that i write blow code in it's onchange event:

```
function onChange() {
$.ajax(
{
url: '/Home/GetProducts/',
type: 'POST',
data: JSON.stringify({ID:$("#Category").val()}),
//contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data){
var jsonres = "";
$.each(data, function (i, variant) {
jsonres += '&lt;option value="' + variant.ID + '">' + variant.Name+ '&lt;/option>';
});
$("#product").html(jsonres);
}
, error: function () { alert('Error'); }
});
}
```

and my Action method is :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetProducts(int? ID)
{
        var res = _teacherUow.GetProducts(ID.GetValueOrDefault()).Select(x => new { x.ID, x.Name }).ToList();
        return Json(new { Result = true, data = res }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

my view code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Category", new SelectList(ViewBag.Category, "ID", "Name"), new {  id = "Category", onchange = "onChange()" })
        &lt;select data-val="true" id="product" name="product">
        &lt;/select>
```

Now i have three problem

1-in the action method parameter receive null

the json result is :

```
{"Result":true,"data":[{"ID":1,"Name":"xxx"},{"ID":3,"Name":"yyyy"}]}
```

2- but the value and text of product drop down list member
is 'undefined'

3- create empty dropdown list for product field with html helper(for fill data member by Ajax request)
can anyone please help me?

Comment: Is the controller being hit (is it GetProducts or GetProduc)? and it should be `$.each(data.data, function (i, variant) {...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue 1: change

```
data: JSON.stringify({ID:$("#Category").val()}),
```

to

```
data: { ID: $("#Category").val()},
```

Issue 2: You are returning an object containing 2 properties `Result` and `data` so the success callback should be

```
$.each(data.data, function (i, variant) {
```

however your not using the `Result` property and it seems pointless anyway so you could just use

```
[HttpGet] // Change this (its a get not a post!)
public ActionResult GetProducts(int? ID) // assume this was a typo
{
  var res = _teacherUow.GetProducts(ID.GetValueOrDefault()).Select(x => new { x.ID, x.Name }); // no need to call ToList()
  return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and in the script use your original code except change `type: 'POST',` to `type: 'GET',`

Issue 3: To create an empty dropdown bound to property `Project` use

```
@Html.DropDownFor(m => m.Project, new SelectList(IEnumerable.Empty<T>))
```

or assign `IEnumerable.Empty<T>` to a view bag property

Note I suggest the following changes to your script

```
$('#Category').change(function() { // remove the `onChange` attribute in the helper
  $('#Project').empty(); // ensure any existing options removed
  $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetProducts", "Home")', { ID: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      var option = $('<option></option>').val(item.ID).text(item.Name);
      $('#Project').append(option);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: tanks for your help i change my code but the action parameter (ID) receive null value

Comment: Works for me. Check the value of `$("#Category").val()` in the console.

Comment: I change to `$("#Category").val()` and test in `alert($("#Category").val())` that show the value but receive null in action and I'm newer in web programing, which console or how to debug jquery code?

Comment: Is the value a valid `int`? And if your writing jquery, you should learn to debug it. [Debugging javascript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: i debug my jquery code and see `data: Object
ID: 1
__proto__: Object` in scope variables of Google chrome.

Comment: If your seeing a value for `data`, then its calling the controller and returning data (put a breakpoint in you controller to check), but that data is not correct since you should be seeing `data: Array[#]`. Check the value of `res` in you controller.

Comment: As a simple test, replace `var res = _teacherUow.GetProducts(...` with `var res = new[] { new { ID = 1, name = "Option 1" }, new { ID= 2, name = "Option 2" } };` and you will see it working.

Comment: no it working correctly i have mistake in action method parameter naming in was `CatID` and I pass `ID` in request ,thanks a lot